# Is there another function faster than ifelse

Tags: r

I have a database that is coded with numbers instead of names.
for example
Less than high school = 0   High school/GED = 1 Some college/trade school = 2   Bachelor'sdegree = 3    Graduate school/advanced degree = 4

I'm using the ifelse function its working but im looking for faster way because its a big data and its time consuming

```
Mass_Shooter_fullDatabase$Education <- ifelse(Mass_Shooter_fullDatabase$Education==0,"Less than high school",
                                      ifelse(Mass_Shooter_fullDatabase$Education==1,"High school/GED",
                                      ifelse(Mass_Shooter_fullDatabase$Education==2,"Some college/trade school",
                                      ifelse(Mass_Shooter_fullDatabase$Education==3,"Bachelor's degree",
                                      ifelse(Mass_Shooter_fullDatabase$Education==4,"Graduate school/advanced degree",NA)))))
```

Comment: `factor(Mass_Shooter_fullDatabase$Education, levels = 0:4, labels = c("Less than high school", "High school/GED", ...))`

Comment: `dplyr::case_when()`

Answer (score 3):

I think using switch case would be much easier than if-else, Please find my answer here

```
library(dplyr)
Education = c(1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Mass_Shooter_fullDatabase = data.frame(Education, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Mass_Shooter_fullDatabase %>% 
  mutate(
    Educations = case_when(
      Mass_Shooter_fullDatabase$Education == 0 ~ "Less than high school",
      Mass_Shooter_fullDatabase$Education == 1 ~ "High school/GED",
      Mass_Shooter_fullDatabase$Education == 2 ~"Some college/trade school",
      Mass_Shooter_fullDatabase$Education == 3 ~"Bachelor's degree",
      Mass_Shooter_fullDatabase$Education == 4 ~"Graduate school/advanced degree"))
```

[image: Sample Output]

Answer (score -1):

I think you could use switch case if such a thing exists in the language you are using. Switch case is available in java.
https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_switch.asp

Comment: In the R help files, `ifelse` is described as "vectorised `switch`" and `switch` is an existing function similar to the one in Java. Please do refrain from answering if you are not sure that you actually know the language about which the question is.